# Bibliography does not appear after running PDFTexify and Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies

In my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[refsection=section]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
author = {Buthor, B.},
year = {2002},
title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
 author = {Cuthor, C.},
 year = {2003},
title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

Some  text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\section{Second}

Some  text \autocite{A01,C03}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

This is how it shows up:

[image]

I have run PDFTexify countless times and also biber and could not get this to work properly. The bibliography did not print and the `\cite` came out as text instead of numbers.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using `biblatex` without any `backend` option: if you have an at-al recent `biblatex` you are therefore expected to use Biber.  Rather than using `texify`, what happens if you start with a 'clean' folder (just `.tex` and `.bib` files) and do `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`?

Comment: If I copy the tex file to a new folder and run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, I get the same error.  Here is what I get when I run biber:                                                     Command Line:   bibtex.exe "4"


This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: 4.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file 4.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file 4.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file 4.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: That's not Biber, it's BibTeX, and unsurprisingly complains as your input will default to Biber. Either rung `biber <filename>` rather than `bibtex <filename>` _or_ add `backend=bibtex` to your options for `biblatex`, then rerun pdfLaTeX before running BibTeX again.

Comment: @Joe, I suppose you are using WinEdt. How do you do to run `biber`? And which version of WinEdt are you using?

Comment: You are correct!  I am using WinEdt.  I was able to change the biblatex.exe to biber.exe in WinEdt and now I am getting the correct output.

Comment: @Joe Take a try at this add-on of mine: [LaTeXify](http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/LaTeXify.php).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is  due to the OP not running the correct tool.